# EntityFramework fluent API "grandchild" relationship mapping

Tags: .net, entity-framework, fluent, database-first, ef-database-first

I'm trying to map what seems like a very common case in the EF fluent API and have hit a wall.  I have the following classes:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
public class Division
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Division Division {get; set;}
}
```

With the following tables:

**Company**
Id - int

**Division:**
Id - int
CompanyId int (FK)

**Employee**
Id - int
Name - varchar(50)
DivisionId - int (FK)

If the Employee table had a CompanyID FK, this mapping would be very simple:

```
HasMany(c=>c.Employees).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(e=>e.CompanyId);
```

However, since I do not have a direct FK from the Employee table to the Company table, I seem to be unable to map the Employees property in the Company object for lazy loading.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot map that. EF code first is only able to map physical relation. So if your employee doesn't have `CompanyId` FK it also doesn't have physical relation with `Company` table. As a workaround you can use non mapped property:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Division> Divisions { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees 
    {
        get
        {
            return Divisions.SelectMany(d => d.Employees);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution will not solve your requirement for lazy loading (it will but in terrible way). Calling `Employees` without loaded relations will execute query to lazy load `Divisions` and after that it will call separate lazy load query to load `Employees` for each `Division` = N + 1 problem. So use this only with eager loading.